# Why am I getting a negative value from $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\frac{-9}{8}}*e^{-16*x^{\frac{-1}{8}}-\frac{2*x}{0.5^{9}}}dx$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

In Mathematica 9, I want to evaluate the following integral:

$\qquad \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\frac{-9}{8}}*e^{-16*x^{\frac{-1}{8}}-\frac{2*x}{0.5^{9}}}dx$

The result should be positive. However, Mathematica gives me -0.0824979.

This is the code from Mathematica in `InputForm`:

```
Integrate[E^(-16/x^8^(-1) - (2*x)/0.5^9)/x^(9/8), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

I don't think I typed a wrong formula.

Could someone help me answering why did Mathematica give me a wrong answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a precision issue.

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)
```

Since you used a machine precision number (i.e., `0.5`) in the integrand, the integration is done with only machine precision.

```
Integrate[E^(-16/x^8^(-1) - (2*x)/(0.5)^9)/x^(9/8), {x, 0, Infinity}]

(* -0.0824979 *)
```

Using exact numbers

```
int = Integrate[E^(-16/x^8^(-1) - (2*x)/(1/2)^9)/x^(9/8), {x, 0, Infinity}]

(* (1/(2^(3/4) \[Pi]^(
 7/2)))MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{-(1/8), 0, 1/8, 1/4, 3/8, 1/2, 5/8, 3/4, 7/
   8}, {}}, 262144] *)
```

If this complicated result is converted to a number using machine precision

```
int // N

(* 0.0270485 *)
```

However, using arbitrary-precision

```
int // N[#, 20] &

(* 5.6160550672798812373*10^-16 *)
```

Comparing with numerical integration

```
int = NIntegrate[E^(-16/x^8^(-1) - (2*x)/(1/2)^9)/x^(9/8), {x, 0, Infinity}]

(* 5.61606*10^-16 *)
```

This value is consistent with the earlier arbitrary-precision result and does not change with increased precision.

```
int = NIntegrate[E^(-16/x^8^(-1) - (2*x)/(1/2)^9)/x^(9/8), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* 5.6160550672798812757*10^-16 *)
```

Looking at the integrand

```
max = NMaximize[
  {E^(-16/x^8^(-1) - (2*x)/(1/2)^9)/x^(9/8),
   x > 0}, x, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* {1.3826054145707193900*10^-13, {x -> 0.0029477253331967126781}} *)

LogPlot[E^(-16/x^8^(-1) - (2*x)/(1/2)^9)/x^(9/8), {x, 1*^-4, 2*^-2}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{x /. max[[2]], Log@max[[1]]}]}]
```

[image]

Consequently, a small value for the integration is expected.

Answer (score 7):

Another case of using non-exact numbers with exact function.

See the difference:

```
integrand = x^(-9/8) Exp[-16 x^(-1/8) - 2 x/(1/2)^9];
Integrate[integrand, {x, 0, Infinity}] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
integrand = x^(-9/8) Exp[-16 x^(-1/8) - 2 x/(0.5)^9];
Integrate[integrand, {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Rule of thumb: use exact numbers when calling exact functions like `DSolve`, `Integrate`, etc.. as *sometimes* when using non-exact numbers, Mathematica result can go wrong.

Comment: Dear @Nasser So, which way should I use?

Comment: @HanaLee Nasser just told you, if you are using an exact function. Use exact numbers. Read the advice, it's extremely good.

Comment: I am not sure. This is exactly what I typed on my screen $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\frac{-9}{8}}*e^{-16*x^{\frac{-1}{8}}-\frac{2*x}{0.5^{9}}}dx$. It apeared on the screen like this.   Is there sth. wrong with it?

Comment: Hana Lee: The term "exact number" here is a _Mathematica_ [jargon term](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html).  Using this jargon, `1/2` is _exact_ and `0.5` is _approximate_.  When _Mathematica_ sees even one approximate number in an expression, it falls back to numerical approximation techniques.  If all terms are exact, then exact symbolic techniques are used (where possible).  In the case at hand, the presence of `0.5` term causes a machine precision approximation to be calculated which differs substantially from the exact symbolic result.

Comment: I have doubts about your numerical values...